# Tensorflow: use None in output_shape in conv2D_transpose

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow

I would like to use a `conv2d_tranpose` (or deconvolution) instead of upsampling in my network.
This requires passing an `output_shape` to the function call. That is not a problem, I can calculate it. But I would like to use None for the batch_size to keep the setup flexible.
Is that possible ?

Here is the line of code:

```
tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(hd_conv1, Wd_conv1, [batch_size, 14,14,64], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding="SAME")
```

`batch_size` is simply a variable that I set at the top of my script. This code runs fine, but if I use `None` instead of `batch_size`:

> TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got None

If I just leave out the first dimension:

> ValueError: output_shape must have shape (4,), got (3,)

I think it is strange that there are different ways to deal with the batch_size. Some operations simply ignore it, such as the normal conv2d, but here I need to specify it explicitly.
In any case I wondered why I would have to calculate the output_shape myself, at all. With given input, strides, padding, that should be easy to calculate.
There is a github [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2118) regarding inference of output_shape, sadly there doesn't seem to be any follow-up.

Am I doing this right - passing in an explicit `batch_size` in the output_shape ?
Is there a way to omit the explicit `batch_size` ?

Comment: The github issue has some explanations. If you don't get it, just follow up over there.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `None`, please use symbolic representation like below.

```
batch_size = tf.shape(something_or_other)[0]  
deconv_shape = tf.pack([batch_size, 40, 40, 32])  
conv2d_transpose(..., output_shape=deconv_shape, ...)
```

Be careful not to use `tf.get_shape()`. `tf.get_shape()` and `tf.shape()` are slightly different.

Also see recomendations in tensorflow site about variable batch size.

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/faq